# polymerized Dimethylbutadiene or "methyl rubber"

Tags: organic-chemistry, materials, rubber

"Methyl rubber", polymerized Dimethylbutadiene, is the first synthetic rubber, but it falls behind polyisoprene having inferior shear strength & oxidizes more easily.

I'm looking into the isomeric composition of these methyl rubber products. Particularly, I'm looking into varieties mostly composed of isomers cis-1,4 & trans-1,4. Typically, ones that have been polymerized with Anionic Chain Polymerization. Have the physical properties of these varieties more of cis-1,4 & trans-1,4 been characterized?